# where to store currentUser

Tags: javascript, database, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple login system and when a user logs in in I store the users data in `sessionStorage` as `"currentUser".` But I discovered that it can be edited. I use google firebase by the way.

Comment: Can you explain more because the currentUser can be store on catch, datbase, session,

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is prevent easy manipulation. JWTs(as a pretty widely used standard) for example solve this by storing a signature on top of the actually relevant data.

If the signature doesn't match a newly generated signature for secret+data anymore, it'll be invalid. Make sure to not share the secret itself with the frontend, because pretty much everything can be read out.

More on JWTs: https://jwt.io/